# edditing a text file in python and making a new text file

Tags: python

I have a big text file with a lot of items. each item has 2 lines. the first line (which is ID line) starts with `>` and the 2nd line which belongs the ID line (which is one line above it) is a sequence of characters. this small example is 2 of the items in my text file (there are many items in the real file one after another).

small example:

```
>NST00000373840.4|ENSG00000119396.6|OTTHUMG00000020582.1|OTTHUMT00000053857.1|RAB14-001|RAB14|4145|UTR5:1-99|CDS:100-199|UTR3:200-221|
ATCTTGGACCAGCCCGAGGAAGATACTGAGGGAGCACAGGAGCAGTCACCGCTGCCACTGCTACTGCCGCTACTGCTGCCGGCGCGTCTGCACCTCTCGGCCTGCCAGTGTACCTGCCGGCGCCTCGGTCGACCGCCCCCGCCCCCTCTCCCGCTGCGTCCGCACTCCTGTTCCTGGTCCTGACGCCCCCCTCCCGCCCGGAAAGCTGCCCAGCCACCAGC
>ENST00000396625.3|ENSG00000081052.10|OTTHUMG00000149892.1|OTTHUMT00000313770.1|COL4A4-001|COL4A4|9895|UTR5:1-150|CDS:151-205|UTR3:206-335|
CGAGAGCGCCGCGAAGAGGCAGCGGGGCGCGGGTGGATTGGGGCTGGAGGTGCGCGTCCCGTGGGGTGGCAAGGCGGCAGCTCCTGGCGCTGCGGGCGTCCCCACAGGAACAGACTTTGACCCAGAACACAGAACCTCACTTGTCAACAAGAACCTTCTGGAAGAGAAGACTGGCAGAATATTTTTTAAGTACTAAGACTTGCCTGCGATGTGGTCTCTGCACATAGTACTAATGAGGTGCTCCTTCAGATTGACCAAGTCCTTGGCCACAGGTCCCTGGTCACTTATACTCATTCTCTTTTCTGTACAATATGTATATGGGAGTGGAAAGAAAT
```

as you see there is `CDS` in the `ID` line and in front of that there is a range of numbers. I want to take this range and extract the characters in the sequence line. for example in the above example for the first `ID`, the range in front of the `CDS` is `100-199` so I want to extract the characters number `100` to the character number `199` as I showed in the expected output. 
also in `ID` line, the columns are `|` separated. in the new file (expected results) for the `ID` I only need the 6th column of the `ID` line.

expected output:

```
>RAB14
CCTGCCAGTGTACCTGCCGGCGCCTCGGTCGACCGCCCCCGCCCCCTCTCCCGCTGCGTCCGCACTCCTGTTCCTGGTCCTGACGCCCCCCTCCCGCCC
>COL4A4
AACCTTCTGGAAGAGAAGACTGGCAGAATATTTTTTAAGTACTAAGACTTGCCT
```

I want to do the same thing for all items in my text file.

for this purpose, at first I am trying to export the file into a `dictionary` in `python` in which the `keys` are `ID` line and the `values` are the sequence. like this dictionary.

```
{'NST00000373840.4|ENSG00000119396.6|OTTHUMG00000020582.1|OTTHUMT00000053857.1|RAB14-001|RAB14|4145|UTR5:1-99|CDS:100-199|UTR3:200-221|': 'ATCTTGGACCAGCCCGAGGAAGATACTGAGGGAGCACAGGAGCAGTCACCGCTGCCACTGCTACTGCCGCTACTGCTGCCGGCGCGTCTGCACCTCTCGGCCTGCCAGTGTACCTGCCGGCGCCTCGGTCGACCGCCCCCGCCCCCTCTCCCGCTGCGTCCGCACTCCTGTTCCTGGTCCTGACGCCCCCCTCCCGCCCGGAAAGCTGCCCAGCCACCAGC', 'ENST00000396625.3|ENSG00000081052.10|OTTHUMG00000149892.1|OTTHUMT00000313770.1|COL4A4-001|COL4A4|9895|UTR5:1-150|CDS:151-205|UTR3:206-335|': 'CGAGAGCGCCGCGAAGAGGCAGCGGGGCGCGGGTGGATTGGGGCTGGAGGTGCGCGTCCCGTGGGGTGGCAAGGCGGCAGCTCCTGGCGCTGCGGGCGTCCCCACAGGAACAGACTTTGACCCAGAACACAGAACCTCACTTGTCAACAAGAACCTTCTGGAAGAGAAGACTGGCAGAATATTTTTTAAGTACTAAGACTTGCCTGCGATGTGGTCTCTGCACATAGTACTAATGAGGTGCTCCTTCAGATTGACCAAGTCCTTGGCCACAGGTCCCTGGTCACTTATACTCATTCTCTTTTCTGTACAATATGTATATGGGAGTGGAAAGAAAT'
```

then the keys can be exported into a list and values will be exported into an other list.

```
ID = d.keys()
Seq = d.values()
CDS_range = []
results = []
for i in ID:
    CDS_range.append(i.split("CDS:"))
for j in range(len(CDS_range)):
    if CDS_range[j] == Seq[j]:
        results.append(Seq[CDS_range[j]])
```

but the results is not like what I want. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You can use the regex `re` module that comes with python. I'm not familiar with it, but it should be useful. Or you can use `line.split('|')` to get each 'column' in the ID line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting as a dict, you can just read lines by splitlines() and use normal split for doing everything else you need. 
Check the below code.

```
sequence = '>NST00000373840.4|ENSG00000119396.6|OTTHUMG00000020582.1|OTTHUMT00000053857.1|RAB14-001|RAB14|4145|UTR5:1-99|CDS:100-199|UTR3:200-221|ATCTTGGACCAGCCCGAGGAAGATACTGAGGGAGCACAGGAGCAGTCACCGCTGCCACTGCTACTGCCGCTACTGCTGCCGGCGCGTCTGCACCTCTCGGCCTGCCAGTGTACCTGCCGGCGCCTCGGTCGACCGCCCCCGCCCCCTCTCCCGCTGCGTCCGCACTCCTGTTCCTGGTCCTGACGCCCCCCTCCCGCCCGGAAAGCTGCCCAGCCACCAGC'
cds = [i for i in sequence.split('|') if 'CDS' in str(i)] # O/P ['CDS:100-199']
from_range = int(cds[0].split(':')[-1].split('-')[0]) # O/P 100
end_range = int(cds[0].split(':')[-1].split('-')[-1]) # O/P 199
required_seq = sequence.split('|')[-1][from_range:end_range] # O/P CCTGCCAGTGTACCTGCCGGCGCCTCGGTCGACCGCCCCCGCCCCCTCTCCCGCTGCGTCCGCACTCCTGTTCCTGGTCCTGACGCCCCCCTCCCGCCC
```

Hope this helps.